# How to convert vmstat and free -m to object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to convert the output from vmstat -s command executed by exec to an object so as well as free -m command out put

I get this from exec for free -m:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7855        2054        1082         257        4718        5243
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

and for vmstat -s i get this output

```
      8044160 K total memory
      2081200 K used memory
      3491012 K active memory
      2508932 K inactive memory
      1131132 K free memory
       579204 K buffer memory
      4252624 K swap cache
      2097148 K total swap
            0 K used swap
      2097148 K free swap
       328672 non-nice user cpu ticks
         3273 nice user cpu ticks
        85460 system cpu ticks
      4215038 idle cpu ticks
        13261 IO-wait cpu ticks
            0 IRQ cpu ticks
          450 softirq cpu ticks
            0 stolen cpu ticks
      2095462 pages paged in
      3761868 pages paged out
            0 pages swapped in
            0 pages swapped out
     10301935 interrupts
     36499667 CPU context switches
   1551158702 boot time
        17506 forks
```

so how can i convert this output to an object like

```
objFreeM = {
  mem: {total: 7855, used: 2054, ...etc},
  swap: {total: 2047, used: 0, free: 2047}
}

objVmstat = {
  totalmemory: 8044160,
  usedmemory: 2081200,
  ....etc
}
```

**this is the result will be like this from vmstat**

`"      8044160 K total memory\n      2517232 K used memory\n      4064068 K active memory\n      2733260 K inactive memory\n       304940 K free memory\n       650300 K buffer memory\n      4571688 K swap cache\n      2097148 K total swap\n            0 K used swap\n      2097148 K free swap\n       454507 non-nice user cpu ticks\n         3803 nice user cpu ticks\n       117177 system cpu ticks\n      7955496 idle cpu ticks\n        15791 IO-wait cpu ticks\n            0 IRQ cpu ticks\n          528 softirq cpu ticks\n            0 stolen cpu ticks\n      2244129 pages paged in\n      4442696 pages paged out\n            0 pages swapped in\n            0 pages swapped out\n     14232293 interrupts\n     50365325 CPU context switches\n   1551158702 boot time\n        22313 forks\n"`

Answer (score 0):

Let's initialize our string:

```
var myString = "      8044160 K total memory\n      2517232 K used memory\n      4064068 K active memory\n      2733260 K inactive memory\n       304940 K free memory\n       650300 K buffer memory\n      4571688 K swap cache\n      2097148 K total swap\n            0 K used swap\n      2097148 K free swap\n       454507 non-nice user cpu ticks\n         3803 nice user cpu ticks\n       117177 system cpu ticks\n      7955496 idle cpu ticks\n        15791 IO-wait cpu ticks\n            0 IRQ cpu ticks\n          528 softirq cpu ticks\n            0 stolen cpu ticks\n      2244129 pages paged in\n      4442696 pages paged out\n            0 pages swapped in\n            0 pages swapped out\n     14232293 interrupts\n     50365325 CPU context switches\n   1551158702 boot time\n        22313 forks\n";
```

Now let's split it:

```
var myArray = myString.split("\n");
```

and then trim the items:

```
for (var index in myArray) myArray[index] = myArray[index].trim();
```

define a helper function for camel-case keys:

```
function camelize(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(letter, index) {
    return index == 0 ? letter.toLowerCase() : letter.toUpperCase();
  }).replace(/\s+/g, '');
}
```

Finaly parse the results:

```
var results = {};
for (var item of myArray) {
    var temp = item.split(" ");
    var value = temp[0];
    var key = "";
    var start = 1;
    if (temp[1] === "K") {
        value += " K";
        start = 2;
    } else {
        key = "";
    }
    for (var index = start; index < temp.length; index++) key += " " + temp[index];
    key = key.trim();
    if (key || value) results[camelize(key)] = value; 
}
```